# How to add a history item from a Redmine plugin (via button/link)

Tags: ruby, plugins, history, redmine

Maybe my request is simple, maybe not. I'm fairly new to ruby and everything and face the problem that I need to add a history item from a plugin. I refer to the ticket system Redmine.

Is there a simple way to trigger an event which adds a predefined comment (like "News sent on [date]")? Preferrably the event should be triggered by pressing a button or clicking a link in the redmine web frontend. Like an additional button/link next to the default ones "edit, watch,...).

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a link, with a href to call a javascript function:

```
<a href="javascript:addNewsEntry()">Add news entry</a>
```

The function should add the text you want in the "issue_notes" text field, and send a submit to the "issue-form" form:

```
function addNewsEntry() {
    $('#issue-notes').value = "News sent on [date]";
    $('#issue-form').submit();
}
```

A good example of this is the [status_button](https://github.com/fanzai0403/status_button) redmine plugin, this might be a good reference for you as:

- it does add some links to the issue page (you also want to add a link to add a new note)
- it does change the status on the issue form and submit it (you also want to change a form field and submit it)